# How to Print Title on Every Page generated By FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

i use FPDF to generate Report From Database and i want the title of the Report to be Printed on the header of the PDF generated

my code look like this

```
function Header()
{
$name="Export PDF";
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
$this->Image('images/pdflogo.png', 5,5,60);
$this->Image('images/hr1.jpg', 10,25,190);
$this->Text(100,25,'$d');

$this->Cell(80);

$this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);

$this->Ln(20);
}
?>
```

can any body show me how to do this Please !!

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$this->Cell(80, 10, 'Example Report Title' );`

It will show Example Report Title on every pages header.